# Facebook-like top navigation CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook, css, facebook-like

I want to make the new Facebook-like top navigation with [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) and [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), as below.

[image]

**And this:**

[image]

As you can see, the arrow of the popbox always under the selected nav and the popbox widths are same. Is there any tutorial or plugin to make this?

Comment: Why don't you Inspect Element and see how they did it, and try and replicate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [**jQuery Notification Menu**](http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/07/jquery-notification-menu/) will be perfect for you. It's a jQuery plugin to add notification bubbles and a notification list to any menu.

[image: Demo image]

You can easily tweak it to your desired style by simply editing the CSS.

[**Check this demo.**](http://www.codebasehero.com/files/notification-menu/demo/index.html)

Comment: I tried it but I can't find out where to add notifications list

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Twitter Bootstrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter_Bootstrap). They got all that cool JavaScript stuff all done for you. They also got a very nice responsive base CSS to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this one is simple.  With the right combination of unordered-lists & fixed-positioned elements you can achieve this quite easily.

1. For the Top Bar, use an unordered list pattern: http://pea.rs/navigation/horizontal-buttons
2. For the Drop down, you have two choices:

   - You can position the dropdown hide it, and then unhide it with [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery).
   - Or use some CSS trickery to position it off of the page until onHover.

To style the dropdown just like that of Facebook, you'll have to do a bit more with CSS to figure out how to get the right shape, but not to worry! There are tutorials / examples on that too!

Tutorials on 'Bubble Point Tooltips':

- *[Bubble Point Tooltips with CSS3 & jQuery](http://css-tricks.com/bubble-point-tooltips-with-css3-jquery/)*
- *[How to Create CSS3 Speech Bubbles Without Images](http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-speech-bubbles/)*

Overall, I recommend the tutorial *[How to Build a Kick-Butt CSS3 Mega Drop-Down Menu](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/)* (it won't take more than 30 minutes to an hour to complete):